# How to update and get Circle new position after dragging using @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm drawing a Circle in a map, and I would like to know how to update and get the new lat, long location of the circle after its been dragged, here is my code so far:

```js
<GoogleMap
  onLoad={loadHandler}
  center={center}
  zoom={zoom}
  mapContainerStyle={{
    height: "70vh",
    width: "100%"
  }}
>
  <Circle
    ref={circleRef}
    center={center}
    radius={1000}
    options={{ fillColor: "#EE80AE33", strokeColor: "#EE80AE66" }}
    draggable={true}
    // onDragStart={}
    onDragEnd={() => console.log(circleRef.current.getCenter())}
  />
</GoogleMap>
```

I tried `onDragEnd={() => console.log(circleRef.current.getCenter())}` but it does not work since I get the original center location

After looking at the documentation [here](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#circle)

And code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/googlemaps-circle-drag-7d049)

Answer (score 2):

I think the center is not updated because `center` is defined in state; the value will always be fixed since it's never manually changed. It's likely the Circle is drawing when dragging but never updating the center internally.

`onDragEnd` passes through a map event, from which you can destructure a `latLng` object with some helpful functions which should return the new center.

```
onDragEnd={(event) => console.log(event.latLng.toString())}
```

Comment: This is great! but it does not give the Circle centre coordinates, it gives the coordinates of the mouse pointer position, so I guess I'll need to calculate an offset and adjust accordingly